# Invalid delete of a pointer to a class

Tags: c++

I seem to be having a problem with my destructor and/or with freeing allocated memory.
Here's my simple code:

```
void* Init(){
    try {
       Facebook* DS = new Facebook();
       return (void*)DS;
    } catch(std::bad_alloc&) {
       return NULL;
    }
}
```

and here's the function releasing the memory allocated by this function:

```
void Quit(void** DS){
   delete (Facebook*)DS;
   *DS = NULL;
   return;
}
```

if im simply calling only these 2 functions im getting an invalid delete at the line of the delete, and the memory allocated by the new was lost.

here's the facebook class:

```
class Facebook {
   private:
   List<Troll*> trollsList;
   AVLTree<PostByLikes> likesTree;
   AVLTree<PostById> idTree;
   int maxPost;
 }
```

and there's no allocating memory being made in the constructor of this class...

Comment: Please take a look at [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) and do away with code like this

Comment: `Quit` should be replaced by a destructor.

Comment: [OT]: `Init()` can be simplified to `return new (std::no_throw) Facebook();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not deleting the `Facebook` object.

Try this:

```
void Quit(void** DS)
{
   delete (*DS);
   *DS = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you're right! I did delete(Facebook*)(*DS) and it worked!

Comment: @OmriShn: could you please accept the answer if it resolves your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
void Quit(void** DS){
   Facebook* pDS = (Facebook*)(*DS);
   delete pDS;
   *DS = NULL;
   return;
}
```